# Getting Apple Mach-o error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm a newbie to iOS, while saving and retrieving data through SQLite, I'm getting Apple Mach-o error (8 errors). I have set the build settings to search library paths but its empty. I have added libz.dylib and libsqlite3 libraries.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController saveData:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController findData:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[ViewController findData:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[ViewController saveData:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController findData:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController saveData:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController findData:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[ViewController saveData:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController findData:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[ViewController saveData:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController findData:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: If You already added Sqlite library then try to clean your code(Window + Shift + k).

Comment: did you added sqlite3 and libz libraries to your project

Answer (score 0):

You haven't linked-in the `sqlite` library (if you think you have then you've done it wrong).